# NotLeaderForPartitionException when using multiple instances in a consumer group in Kafka+SparkStreaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I've been experimenting with multiple consumer instances in a Kafka consumer group but it always fails with kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException.

My Kafka cluster consists of 3 brokers and the topic that has `PartitionCount:2`and `ReplicationFactor:3`.

SparkConsumer.java

```
public class SparkConsumer {

private static Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> MyReducerFunc = (a, b) -> a + b;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: SparkConsumer <brokers> <topics>\n" +


       "  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers\n" +
              "  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from\n\n");
          System.exit(1);
        }

        //StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();

        String brokers = args[0];
        String topics = args[1];

        SparkConf sparkConf = new  SparkConf().setMaster("local[5]").setAppName("SparkConsumer").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        // Create a StreamingContext with a 2 second batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(2)); 

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
        //kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "SparkConsumerGrp");
        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");

        // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicsSet
        );
        //Aggregate data every 30 sec
        JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages2 =
                messages.window(Durations.seconds(30), Durations.seconds(30));


        messages2.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

            long numHits = rdd.count();

            if(numHits == 0)
                System.out.println("No new data fetched in last 30 sec");

            //Do Processing
            else{
                    System.out.println("\n\n----------------------------------Data fetched in the last 30 seconds: " + rdd.partitions().size()
                            + " partitions and " + numHits  + " records------------------\n\n");

                    //Convert to java log object    
                    JavaRDD<ApacheAccessLog> logs = rdd.map(x-> x._2)
                                                        .map(ApacheAccessLog::parseFromLogLine)
                                                            .cache();

                    //Find the bot ip addresses
                    JavaRDD<String> iprdd =  logs.mapToPair(ip-> new Tuple2<>(ip.getIpAddress(),1))
                            .reduceByKey(MyReducerFunc)
                                .filter(botip-> botip._2 > 50)
                                    .keys();

                    //If we find something, we store it in results dir on hdfs

                    if(iprdd.count() > 0)
                    {
                        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
                        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
                        //sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", timeStamp);
                        iprdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/results/"+timeStamp);
                        JobConf jobConf=new JobConf();
                                System.out.println("\n\n-------------Resuts successfully written to /results on hdfs-------------\n");
                    }

                }        

        });



        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
}
}
```

My understanding from the [documentation](http://http:/https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) was that we can start another consumer process with the same groupid to add that instance to an existing group. Hence, I run this code on two separate terminals. However, this is the error that I always get:

At the first instance:

```
    17/06/06 00:53:26 ERROR DirectKafkaInputDStream: ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([topic5,1])) 
17/06/06 00:53:26 ERROR DirectKafkaInputDStream: ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leaders for Set([topic5,0], [topic5,1]))
17/06/06 00:53:27 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1496735582000 ms
org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leaders for Set([topic5,0], [topic5,1]))
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.WindowedDStream.compute(WindowedDStream.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leaders for Set([topic5,0], [topic5,1]))
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.WindowedDStream.compute(WindowedDStream.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

At the second instance: (seems to occur when I'm calling the `rdd.count()` and happens right after the first instance crashes)

```
    Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at hadoopTest.hadoopTest.SparkConsumer.lambda$1(SparkConsumer.java:85)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:255)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
... 2 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>hadoopTest</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoopTest</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>hadoopTest</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
         <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
         <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
         <version>0.8.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
         <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>0.8.2.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
               <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
               <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
               <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
               <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-tags_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
         <version>2.11.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
         <version>2.10.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
         <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
         <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have been trying to debug this the whole day and am at a loss. It says it cannot find the leaders even though all my brokers remain up. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11` instead of `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11`. Also you need to change version for `kafka-clients` to `0.10.2.0` to match with it.